# Replace all occurrences of a $ symbol in between class and the first function in sublime text

Tags: php, regex, sublimetext3

I did a really stupid mistake after reading about `var` in PHP7 and I mistakenly thought that I don't need neither `var` nor `public` to declare variables inside of a class (outside of it's methods). So I removed it from 400+ files and did some refactoring on pretty much all of them. So I can't just revert back, because that would leave me with even more work.

Now I get a fatal error and I need to add either `private` or `public` to all variables declared that way. I'm not sure if any of these classes actually need public variables, probably `private` should be enough.

But I can't figure out if it's even possible to do in Sublime Text 3. I tried many different combinations of regex, but none of them worked. I'm guessing that I might need a script to run though all files instead, but maybe I'm overlooking something...

So I have something like this:

```
class MyClass {
    $myvar1;
    $myvar2;

    function __construct($myvar1 = NULL, $myvar2 = array()) {
        $this->myvar1 = $myvar1;    
        $this->myvar2 = $myvar2;    
    }
}
```

And I want to turn it into this:

```
class MyClass {
    private $myvar1;
    private $myvar2;

    function __construct($myvar1 = NULL, $myvar2 = array()) {
        $this->myvar1 = $myvar1;    
        $this->myvar2 = $myvar2;    
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Please note that there are no comments (neither C/C++ nor # style) between the class declaration and its first function. Also string notation should not be considered. The solution should solve specifically this issue, because it seems to be impossible to make it universal for all possible cases. It seems that using `\G` modifier is the key to solve this particular issue the way I wanted to. So use the answer with caution.

I think I need to replace all occurrences of `$` with `private $` in between `class` and the first occurrence of `function`. Could it be possible just with Sublime Text 3?

So far I fail at even finding all occurences of a pattern that starts with `class` and ends with the first `function`. Currently I'm trying to improve the following regex: `(?s)class (.*?){.+function`. For some reason the selection ends at the last function, not the first one and I can't figure out how to fix that. As the worst option I could use this pattern to search through all 400+ files and then edit them manually, but that would be a pain, of course...

PS: is it even a good practice to declare them there if I assign them in the `__construct` method anyway?

Comment: Best thing to do: Use a repo so that you can revert back to an older version of the file!

Comment: Reverting this change would also revert numerous changes that I did afterwards (I did it late at night and was in a hurry, so I didn't test every step...), so I consider it only as the last option and would rather add `private` manually in all these 400+ files, because refactoring them again would take even more time.

Comment: @ctwheels, I just tried your regex in sublime and it worked! I just used search and replace everywhere (after adding the folder to sublime). It replaced it properly everywhere! Hell, that's quite a tricky pattern for me :) You can make it an answer and I'll mark it. Thank you a lot!

Comment: maybe you should get rid of `(?s)` and match in "multiline" mode so you can utilize beginning of string anchor and identify your variable declarations by virtue of the fact that they exist on a line by themselves:  `^\s*(\$\w+);` and replace with `\tprivate $1;`  (worked fine in ST3 btw)   https://regex101.com/r/FGVyVY/2/

Comment: Does PHP allow variables declared anywhere inside a class? Or, do they have to be declared before any functions at the top of the class? If so, the `\G` construct won't work.

Comment: @sweaver2112, your pattern would also match variable declarations inside of class methods and that's unwanted behavior. A pattern by Ctwheels indeed seems much more complex, but it also works exactly how I need it.

Comment: @sln, that's a question of style preference. I think the code would even work without them declared there, because they are getting assigned in the `__construct` method. However, I think it's a good practice to declare all variables of a class like that, just for readability (and also to set their visibility). Some people prefer to put them in the end of the class or before the methods that use them, but personally I prefer variable declaration to be in one place.

Comment: I don't really care how crappy PHP is. Anybody that lands on this page will think they have a regex solution you accepted, which is bogus. I mean you could get a better solution, but you chose the dirty with the quick.

Comment: @sin, ah, I see what you mean. Yes, this regex wouldn't work with variables declared somewhere further, after the methods. But my question also specifies this specific case where we need to replace it between the class declaration and its first method. I think you can improve it to work with all occurrences outside of methods, but that would be extra to the question. I think the accepted answer is good enough, since it solves the described issue. Feel free to add your answer though, I'd upvote it if it's more universal.

Comment: @sln I've added another regex to my solution to help future readers in the case of comments or constants.

Comment: `I think I need to replace all occurrences of $ with private $ in between class and the first occurrence of function` in Rev 2. See if you can word that into the title. Also, in the body, see if you can communicate that comments (C/C++ style and #) are not in this area. Also, specify that string notation should not be considered (if allowed in class declarations). State that basically, you want a custom regex that can only be satisfied using the `\G` anchor. When done, the result is you've accepted the right answer.

Comment: @sln, thanks! I added an edit where I think it fits and also changed the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regex will only match variables after the class's opening and will not work after a comment or constant declaration. [See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/A8yhdk/1)

```
(?:\bclass \w+\s*{\s*|\G(?!\A)\s*)\K(\$\w+\s*(?:;|=.*;))
```

For a regex that works around comments and constants as well you can use the following ([see regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/A8yhdk/2)). Note that this, once again, only works for variables at the top of a class:

```
(?:\bclass \w+\s*{\s*|\G(?!\A)\s*(?:(?://|#).*$|/\*[\s\S]*?\*/|\bconst[^;]*;)\s*)\K(\$\w+\s*(?:;|=.*;))
```

If variables are declared after the top of the class, your best bet for a *quick and dirty* solution is to use the whitespace as an indicator of what belongs to the class and what doesn't. Assuming you use proper indentation of either 1 tab character or 4 space characters, you can use [`^(?:\t| {4})\K(\$\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/A8yhdk/3)

Replacement: `private $1`

- `(?:\bclass \w+\s*{\s*|\G(?!\A)\s*)` Matches either of the following:

  - `\bclass \w+\s*{\s*`

    - `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
    - `class` Match this literally
    - `\w+` Match one or more word characters
    - `\s*{\s*` Match any number of whitespace, followed by `{`, followed by any number of whitespace
  - `\G(?!\A)\s*` Assert position at the end of the previous match and match any number of whitespace
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `(\$\w+\s*(?:;|=.*;))` Capture the following into capture group 1

  - `\$\w+\s*` Match `$` literally, followed by one or more word characters then any number of whitespace
  - `(?:;|=.*;)` Match either `;` or `=` followed by any character any number of times and then `;`

Comment: This won't work if a constant is defined in between.

Comment: @revo I was thinking that at first too, but OP said that they accidentally removed `var` (they never mentioned `const`)

Comment: @revo I originally suggested this in the comments section and the OP responded to me telling me that it worked for their situation and asked me to write an answer so that they could mark it as answered. I completely agree with you that there are many other test cases that should be considered, but for a *quick and dirty* solution that *fixes* the issue the OP is experiencing, this works. The OP specified `in between class and the first occurrence of function`

Comment: @revo I completely agree. I originally simply asked the OP if my suggested regex worked for them (since they were looking for a quick and dirty solution). If we want to get into more detailed information about this then we can conclude regex is not even the best tool for this as it can't effectively check against comments (what if we have `$x;` in the comments?). This is simply the bare minimum as required by the OP to quickly fix their mistake. I'm aware many improvements can be made with this regex to get it to work around comments and others. It works for the OP's test case and requirements

Comment: @revo if we really want to get more nitpicky about this, we could say that [`(?:\bclass \w+\s*{\s*|\G(?!\A)\s*(?:(?://|#).*$|/\*[\s\S]*?\*/|\bconst[^;]*;)\s*)\K(\$\w+\s*(?:;|=.*;))`](https://regex101.com/r/A8yhdk/2) works for *some* of those special cases, but I'm sure you could find something to break that logic too. I've updated my answer to include that regex as well.

Answer (score 3):

Although accepted answer may fit OP needs, it has much pitfalls. It doesn't work if properties have comments, or class extends another class or implements an interface or constants are defined between properties or comma separated declarations do exist.

You may find this regex more accurate (not bulletproof though):

```
(?m)function(*COMMIT)(*F)|^\s*\K\$\S+\s*[=;,]
```

Put `private $0` as replacement string.

Comment: I assume classes reside in separate PHP files.